# SQL request from table A to table B with random values

Tags: python, sql, pandas, python-2.7, sqlite

I have two tables like this

```
table_A:                                        table_B:                  

id    reference_1      reference_2          id   data_1       id data_2       
1     gh32             chocolate             1    abc          ab28
2     fg52             cacao                 2    def          cd98    
3     cd98             cofe                  3    ghi          fg52
4     ab28             milk                  4    klm          gh32
```

The two tables contain multiples rows and columns.

Here is my pseudo code considering values of table_B appear randomly and the process have to take all the lines of the table_B.

```
take row 1 in table_B
search where is data_2 in table_A, reference_1
print the complete row of table_A adding data_1 of table_B
```

I can code some actions in python 2.7 if needed.
Thanks you for the help..

Comment: I'm sorry, but your Pseudocode is not very clear, also it's not clear how you store your data and what kind of code you have already. Also it looks a little like homework to me.

Comment: @Qohelet I'm a noob on code sorry man, also it's not homework the whole code is much more complicated, just stucked in this particular situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want sql then you need a join of the 2 tables like this:

```
select a.*, b.data_1
from table_b b inner join table_a a
on b.data_2 in (a.reference_1, a.reference_2)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gUcJi6qhCJikZ2V18wnYBq/0).
Results:

```
| id  | reference_1 | reference_2 | data_1 |
| --- | ----------- | ----------- | ------ |
| 1   | gh32        | chocolate   | klm    |
| 2   | fg52        | cacao       | ghi    |
| 3   | cd98        | cofe        | def    |
| 4   | ab28        | milk        | abc    |
```

Comment: Thanks you @forpas you help me a lot!
one more question :
If I need to add another column to table_B like data_3 with ('hot','cold')
and I say: if hot = print all row of table_A but not milk

Comment: If I understood you need a where clause: `where b.data_3 = 'hot' and a.reference_2 <> 'milk'`. If this is not what you need add the data to the demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gUcJi6qhCJikZ2V18wnYBq/0 save it and post the link with your expected result.

Comment: this is exactly what I search! but I don't see how adding this parameter at your query ( I updated the demo) or is it only possible in a separate query ?

Comment: Is this that you want: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gUcJi6qhCJikZ2V18wnYBq/3

Comment: exactly, thanks again ! the "<>" was the missing link. I have to learn SQL better